# Why animation doesn't finish before callback

Tags: jquery, callback, slide

In my learning I have always learnt and understood callbacks in jQuery like this:

> A callback function is executed after the current animation (effect) is finished.
>
> [...] with animations, the next line of code can be run even though the animation is not finished. This can create errors.
> To prevent this, you can create a callback function. The callback function will not be called until after the animation is finished.
> *<sup>Citation: [www.w3schools.com[...]](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp)</sup>*

and

> A callback is a function that is passed as an argument to another function and is executed after its parent function has completed.
> *<sup>Citation: [www.jquery.com[...]](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works)</sup>*

But *my* callback use doesn't work for some reason.

Look at the following code:

```
$(page).slideUp("slow", function() {
                               
    $('div#details').html(details);
    $(page).slideDown("slow");              

});
```

This should make the contentbox slide up and therefore disappear, then the content is changed to something new, and lastly the contentbox slides down (appears) again. I need these three steps to happen after one another in this order, but each step must only begin when the previous has finished. That is why I use a callback instead of just having this:

```
$(page).slideUp("slow");
                               
$('div#details').html(details);
                            
$(page).slideDown("slow");
```

Which will make everything happen at the same time.

My code works, and I can shift the page content at a click of a button. But the animations don't react as I expected from this. When the button is clicked, the content immediately disappears without any animated slideUp. The new content does then slideDown in a fine animation.

[Click around the left sidemenu here, to see what happends.](http://www.nebulafilm.dk/productions/spor_8/index.html)

I don't understand why there is no animated slideUp, but I suspect the callback doesn't act like I thought it would. It seems that the callback fires when the first animation starts, instead of waiting to fire until the animation has finished. Or maybe it's just the slideUp that doesn't work at all?

Can anyone explain to me, what I don't know and don't see in this extremely simple code including a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the slideDown in the callback

```
$(page).slideUp("slow", function() {

    $('div#details').html(details);
    $(page).slideDown("slow");
});
```

Your previous code only updated the div #details upon completion of slideUp.

Comment: Doesn't work. It seems the slideUp just won't do anything. I have now done that it in my code on the site, and still no luck. But thanks for the comment. You are absolutely right, the last line should of course also be inside the callback (in theory). I have edited it into my question and voted your answer up.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming page is a variable - what is actually supposed to be sliding up?

Comment: After looking at your source code, I'm thinking it's not sliding up because it is getting removed from the DOM before it has a chance to. Check your 2 lines above it - the unwrap and the wrap() before that. Try putting those two lines inside the slideUp callback.

Comment: The outer box in which the content should slide is `div#details`. `page` contains the id of the boxes (which are initially hidden) where the actual content is stored. And `details` is the content in `page` and alway inside a div (since tables makes it all very smashy).

Comment: Well, these wrapper lines were not the answer, but you lead me in the right direction. I had an error somewhere else on the page. I don't know exactly why the slideUp didn't work when the slideDown did - it was like half of the script worked even though the error was there. But thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you got it working - sorry I fell asleep after my last comment, it was like 4am haha.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the delay function as a workaround.

```
$(page).slideUp(500);
$('div#details').html(details);
$(page).delay(500).slideDown(500);
```